# SQL Delete Rows with Constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, sql-delete

I am doing some Exercises and for that I want to delete a Row which is referenced with a Primary/Foreign Key.

Is it possible to delete those Rows without deleting the ones which it has a Relationship with? (like On Delete Cascade)

I also know that I can Disable the constraints, however I want to try deleting without disabling the Constraints.

Comment: I'm lost.  The reason for disabling constraints is to do what you want to do.  Why don't you want to disable them?

Comment: You can change them to `on delete set null`

Comment: @GordonLinoff i always thought there was a risk in doing that.
if there is not, then i would do that without question.

Comment: @Sejachu . . . The risk in disabling constraints is that you affect the data integrity.  You seem to want to mess up your data integrity, so I don't see a particular additional risk.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would enable the constraints after deleting the rows. Would that still affect the data integrity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row can always be deleted unless its primary key is referenced as a foreign key in a row from another table. In this case, attempting to delete rows will result in an error when the primary/foreign key relationship against data is encountered. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` option can be used to work around this and delete records from the child table when rows are removed from the parent table.

If you only want to delete the rows that **do not have** a relationship, then you can exclude the rows that **do have** a relationship from the delete operation using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM table2 b
   WHERE b.table1Id = a.id
)
```